# Launch another activity if checkbox is checked

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, manifest

When my application starts, login Activity appears. It contains checkbox "sign me next time". I want to start another Activity next time of application starting and send username and password of user to it if checkbox was checked.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to save the username and checkbox value in the SharedPreferences.
After that you can retrieve them when the application starts.

Example:

```
//Saving the values
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username",username);
editor.putString("password",password);
editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isCheckBoxChecked);
editor.commit();

//Retrieving the values
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isChecked"))
{
     //Do whatever you need to do if it's checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences` to save your username and password. When your activity starts, check whether they are stored in `Shared Preferences`. U can find many good examples of `Shared Preferences` in google.

Answer (score 0):

In your Login Activity do the below,

```
 pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 intent = new Intent(context, LaunchingActivity.class);

 isChecked = pref.getBoolean("isChecked", false); 
 if(isChecked)
      startActivity(intent);


 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            username = userEdtTxt.getText().toString();
            password = pwdEdtTxt.getText().toString();
        }

        if(checkBox.isChecked()) {              
            editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("username", username);
            editor.putString("password", password);
            editor.putString("isChecked", true);
            editor.commit();
        }   
        startActivity(intent);      
    }

 });
```

Then in the launching activity do this,

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 String username = pref.getString("username", "");
 String password = pref.getString("password", "");
```